# Can a continent be completely desert?

Tags: environment, geography, deserts

I want my continent to be at least 90% desert. It has a square shape with several peninsulas. Kinda like Australia, but more than 3 times bigger and it's not flat(well it does have flat areas, but not to the extent like Australia). It's area is equal to that of North America, or 25,000,000 km2. My continent is located exactly on Earth like planet, in the tropic of Capricorn.

Comment: I was going to write up an answer on Antarctica, which is both a continent and the world's largest desert, but it doesn't fit the requirement for being in the tropics.

Comment: Just relax your requirement from full "desert" to "arid". Australia comes very, very close already then.

Comment: Homeland: desert of Kharak?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Get another continent to the west/northwest so that there will be no monsoons in your main one**

Tropical location is already makes the region prone to be desert, because this latitude is affected by the downstream circulation of the [Hadley cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadley_cell). However, unless something moist air from traveling at low altitudes from the southeast in the North - or northwest in the South, that part of your continent would be subjected to monsoons (so even it's arid, it won't be 90% desert).

There may be two solutions to that. One is to have a very massive mountain range blocking air circulation (like @SoronelHaetir had suggested). Another is to place a considerable landmass in the area where your continent would otherwise be getting its water. For example, Arabian peninsula would have been a wet place if not for the Indian subcontinent which absorbs all monsoons.

[image: Earth deserts]

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet would be to have an absolutely massive mountain range on the coast wherever the prevailing winds come from to create a rain shadow for the rest of the land.

Comment: Since the continent itself should be flat, maybe a mountain range (a bit like New Zeeland) just off the coast so it's separate but still correctly positioned?

Comment: @DWKraus looks the other way around - OP specified that the continent should NOT be flat.

Answer (score 3):

**High elevation.**

https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/High-elevation_deserts

> High-elevation deserts are not like the low-lying Sahara, and are
> instead inland from oceans. They share some features in common with
> continental climates, though these deserts' high elevation reduces
> temperature. Since higher latitudes with similar precipitation
> patterns typically feature tundra or ice cap climates, high deserts
> are typically closer to the equator than the North Pole..
>
> While deserts are sometimes defined by arbitrary precipitation totals,
> such as 10 in (250 mm) a year, there are many places around the world
> that receive more than this amount but would still be considered "dry"
> by temperate-climate standards. Some of the places mentioned in this
> article include annual rainfall totals above 10 inches per year, but
> still largely or completely share the flora of a desert, and therefore
> are designated as "high-elevation deserts" for the sake of this
> article's scope.

The Tibetan plateau is sizewise the closest thing our world has to what you want.  At 25,000,000 square km it is 10% of the size that you ask for.  It is still big.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_Plateau

> The plateau is a high-altitude arid steppe interspersed with mountain
> ranges and large brackish lakes. Annual precipitation ranges from 100
> to 300 millimetres (3.9 to 11.8 in) and falls mainly as hail. The
> southern and eastern edges of the steppe have grasslands that can
> sustainably support populations of nomadic herdsmen, although frost
> occurs for six months of the year. Permafrost occurs over extensive
> parts of the plateau. Proceeding to the north and northwest, the
> plateau becomes progressively higher, colder, and drier, until
> reaching the remote Changtang region in the northwestern part of the
> plateau. Here the average altitude exceeds 5,000 metres (16,000 ft)
> and winter temperatures can drop to −40 °C (−40 °F).

The high desert stays dry because air ascending along the slopes at its edges lose moisture as it ascends, cools, and falls in pressure.  The edges of this continent where it meets the ocean will be rainy and wet.  Up on the plateau the high elevation keeps things drier than they would be lower, because evaporation happens faster at lower air pressure.

I think the possibility of steppes is nice because nomads are cool   Ferocious hail and endorrheic lakes are another neat aspect of a plateau continent like this.  You might see a lake in the distance and arrive to find it is saltier than the ocean.  Endorrheic lakes can have some weird stuff going on.

[image: mono lake tufa towers]
https://www.americansouthwest.net/california/mono_lake/index.html

Comment: Not necessarily so.  High elevations can be quite wet.  Consider the highlands of New Guinea or Washington's Olympic Peninsula & Cascade Range.  Your Mono Lake example is dry not because of altitude (it's only about 6K ft/2K m), but because it's in the rain shadow of the higher Sierra Nevada just to the west.